# How can I eager load across 2 DBs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have to interact with some data in a legacy DB which is not part of my application. I need to load data from both sources without causing n+1 queries.

**thing.rb**

```
class Thing
  # Lives in my applications DB
  belongs_to :other_thing
end
```

**other_thing.rb**

```
class OtherThing
  establish_connection(:other_database)
  has_many :things
end
```

`Thing.includes(:other_thing)`
Does not work because other_things is in a different schema.

`Thing.all.map(&:other_thing)` 
Works, but generates n+1 queries.

So far, this is the best I've come up with:

```
things = Thing.all
other_things = OtherThing.find(things.map(&:other_thing_id))
things = things.map{|t| t.other_thing = other_things.select{|ot| ot.id == t.other_thing_id}.first; t }
```

This only results in 2 queries, but I think a better solution must exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preload` to do that:

```
Think.preload(:other_thing)
```

Contrary to what [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-preload) says it does *not* work like `#include`.

Comment: https://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html